# EC2 Create new Linux user(s) with their OWN Key Pairs?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, key-pair

In EC2, i spinned a `CentOS v6.5` instance, and i got a `Key Pair` as well (of course). But the problem is, i hoped it would be like as usual before that it would creates the `ec2-user` user, so that i can use the `ec2-user` name and login with that `key pair`.

But now is not. Instead the key is for `root` directly. And there also is no `ec2-user`.

So my basic question would be:

- How to creates each of additional (new) users, *(now lets call "michael" as one new user)*, to be logged in by using their NEWLY generated (own different) `key pairs` `.pem` files? *(So that "michael" doesn't need to use the Password, but just use it own `key pair`)*
- Again, another new user with new key-pair again. *(Lets say, the user `annie`)*

*Note: It would be really appreciable if a simple (straight-forward) step-by-step instruction can be provided.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create the user:

```
# useradd michael
```

Generate a key pair for him:

```
# ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f key -C michael
```

Above command will create tow files: `key` and `key.pub`

Create `.ssh` directory for michael and copy the `.pub` file as below:

```
# su - michael
# mkdir .ssh && cd .ssh
# cat > authorized_keys < key.pub
# chmod 0700 ~/.ssh; chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Handover `key` to michael. This is nothing but the private key. Usually AWS appends `.pem` to the private keys.

Now michael can login with private key `key` as below:

```
ssh -i key michael@<ec2_host_name>
```

Comment: Official documentation is not useful. Just a couple of minutes with this and I was done. Thanks. Earlier I was creating .ssh using root, So I had to change the permission of authorized_keys.

Comment: i am getting Authentication failed.error for that new user when i am connecting filezilla or ssh

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this, is during the instance init using cloud-init and user data.

Copy and paste the following script into the User Data field while creating your EC2 instance.

For **username**, enter the new user's user name. For **ssh-rsa AB3nzExample**, enter your public key.

```sh
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [users-groups,always]
users:
  - name: username
    groups: [ wheel ]
    sudo: [ "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" ]
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh-authorized-keys: 
    - ssh-rsa AB3nzExample
```

This can be easily automated if you are using Terraform.